# С помощью Intent надо получить адрес картинки и передать в Picasso

Tags: java, android, android-intent, imageview, picasso

Есть код:

```
Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        in.setType("image/*");
                        in=Intent.createChooser(in,"Виберіть картинку");
                        startActivityForResult(in,REQUEST_CODE);
```

Адрес я получаю  `content: // media / external / images / media / 8967`

Однако Picasso не загружает его:
`Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(recipe.getUrl()).into(imageView);`

ну и

`protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri;
            if (data!=null)
            {
                uri=data.getData();
                 Recipe recipe=getRecipeFromFragment();
                recipe.setUrl("file://" + uri.toString());
                Log.i("uri", recipe.getUrl());
                RecipeLab.getInstance(this).updateRecipe(recipe);
            }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(recipe.getUrl())).into(imageView);
```

Или

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File("сontent://media/external/images/media/8967")).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Можно попробовать но Picasso загружает картинки также из интернета